# How to dynamically add scripts tag at each Sub-domain level through single angular application?

Tags: node.js, angular, subdomain, dynamic-script-loading

I have tired some of DOM operation like,

```html
document.createElement

document.write
```

The `document.createElement` way requires a standard script structure . But in my case it can be either a java script function or script link.

The `document.write` operation overwrite the entire script when used inside `app.component` and only inside the `app.component` I have the dynamic data at Sub-domain level.

Didn’t work as expected .

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically load a script and skip the angular pipeline? Regardless of how to do this, you should ask yourself _why_ you need to do this. There is most likely a much more elegant solution to this.

Comment: If there is feedback you can provide, please expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the same application on different sub-domains so it seems like you're looking at deploying an application to different environments with different scripts depending on which environment.

I recommend using the environment files in `\src\environments\`. You can set the scripts like this:

```
environment.ts:

export const environment = {
  version: require('../../custom-script-for-environment1.json')
};

environment.subdomain.ts:

export const environment = {
  version: require('../../custom-script-for-environment2.json')
};
```

and then import it where needed:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Read more about environments in this Angular blog:

https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/